# GeoNode-Project: cannot find geonode base templates

Tags: django-templates

I’m trying to [customize the look](https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/devel/workshops/index.html#customize-the-look-and-feel) of an instance of a GeoNode Project and I can’t find the base templates. The templates folder has only [this file](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-project/tree/master/src/project_name/templates/geonode-mapstore-client).
I have installed according to the [official tutorial](https://docs.geonode.org/en/master/install/advanced/project/index.html#ubuntu-20-04).

How can I access the base templates from GeoNode, in a GeoNode Project instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting with a geonode-project not all geonode templates appear.

Also, GeoNode behaves quite differently in versions <4 and >=4. Customizing in versions <4 will be more appropriate for those who are more familiar with Django and HTML templating, while in versions >=4 requires some more detailed knowledge in css/js and node-js.

[Here is some material](https://training.geonode.geo-solutions.it/GN4/index.html) that may be useful for creating a geonode-project and customizing the interface in GeoNode 3.3.1.